# How to estimate current situation of an old site not created by myself before i launch my new one?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, seo

I need to do `SEO` and need to show improvements and a summery of new trends for a site.It is a replacement for an old site. How i can prove that i have done a good job on `SEO`,using `google analytic` and `Facebook Conversion Tracking`.Is there a way to get current site statistics? Then i can show, i have brought him more viewers to his new site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programing releated

Answer (score 2):

If the previous site doesn't already include `google analytics` tracking codes then no, it doesn't keep track of any statistics. You can implement them though to the old website keep it up for a month or so, gather the data required and when you launch the new one, then compare them.

If you don't know how to add tracking codes, take a look [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en).